# Visual Studio Code PHP validation error: Cannot validate since /usr/bin/php is not a valid php executable

Tags: php, validation, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I'm trying to setup PHP validation in Visual Studio Code which is running in Linux Mint 19. I added PHP executablePath as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com). What am I doing wrong?

```
settings.json
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
}
```

PHP info:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php

$ php -v
PHP 7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
(built: Mar  7 2019 20:31:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.3, 
Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies 
with Zend OPcache v7.3.3-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 
Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

System info:

```
Operating System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon
Cinnamon Version: 3.8.9
Linux Kernel:     4.15.0-20-generic
```

Comment: Please explain what happens. Does anything work?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a permission issue about Visual Studio Code. It tries to execute the PHP but can not access it and does not give an error related to this issue. You can just copy the executable to home folder.

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/php /home/$USER/php
```

After that you can add this line to the settings.json

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/home/<your-user-name>/php"
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but linting still doesn't seem to work. There is no red underline on code and no error output. The solution also doesn't seem to be the best, is there any way to fix permission issue, without moving the PHP executable?

Comment: Please go to Terminal window in Visual Studio Code and click Run Active File and please share what happens. Ofcourse, there are other ways, one of them is giving permission to vscode under user groups.

Comment: Output: permission denied

Comment: Could you try now chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.php

Comment: Output: `line 1: ?php: No such file or directory` and many command not found errors. Linting still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run this command on bash or vscode sh terminal. VSCode jus[t reads the /home/$USER folder. It is too weird. Please run command in bash and then run pwd on vscode sh terminal

Comment: I did both now. `$ pwd` `/home/ignas`

Comment: Okey now put your php file to /home/ignas/ and open it with vscode try again. If it works next time check your path in vscode and try to change folder to where your script files stored with $ cd

Comment: It was always in /home/ignas

Comment: you mean yourscript.php stands there?

Answer (score -3):

open setting JSON file from that error message and paste the following:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

Comment: That path is for Windows, and the question is Linux related.

Comment: Yes this solution is for windows if the same problem exists on windows.